# Multiple dissociated sequential IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'm building an imageboard/forum engine. 
By design, every thread/post in a sub-forum have a sequential ID, like Github's issues, where every issue ID is bound to it's repository:

> When creating a new thread on Games sub-forum, your thread would have ID 1, if someone reply, its post (reply) ID would be 2 and so on...

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id | parent |   board    |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 | null   | games      |
|  2 | null   | games      |
|  3 | 1      | games      |
|  1 | null   | music      |
|  1 | null   | television |
|  2 | 1      | music      |
+----+--------+------------+
```

I've seen some implementations that creates a new table for every new sub-forum, but I don't like this approach because I have to know all sub-forums in advice to make a query.

Is there a "best" approach, something like Github does with repo's issues?

PS: I'm going to use Postgresql

Comment: Shouldn't the second record have a `parent` value of `1`?

Comment: When starting the thread, create a new `threadID` and give all messages belonging to this thread this ID.  Also give each message within the thread (incuding the first one) an incrementing `messageID`.

Comment: Can a reply also be the start of a subthread?

Comment: @toonice nope, because it's a thread, not a reply!

Answer (score 0):

When starting the thread, create a new `threadID` and give all messages belonging to this thread this ID. Also give each message within the thread (including the first one) an incrementing `messageID`.  For example...

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| threadID | messageID | board      |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| 1        | 1         | games      |
| 1        | 2         | games      |
| 1        | 3         | games      |
| 2        | 1         | music      |
| 2        | 2         | music      |
| 1        | 4         | games      |
| 3        | 1         | television |
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

When starting a new thread, set `threadID` to `MAX( threadID ) + 1` and set `messageID` to the arbitrary value of `1`.  Similarly, when continuing a thread, set `threadID` to the thread's existing `threadID` value and `messageID` to `MAX( messageID ) + 1`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: But how do I make the threadID autoincrement to be bound to its board?